# e2fsck reports errors on my root partition from terminal window, but not on single-user mode

Tags: linux, ext4, filesystem-corruption

I discovered some corrupt user files in my home directory, which is part of the root partition.

When I run `e2fsck -nf /dev/sda2` I get the following:

```
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Warning!  /dev/sda2 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 3540701 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 3540770 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3543800 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(12097070--12097071) -(12702285--12702286) -(12704775--12704776)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (14619606, counted=14663655).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -3540701 -3540770 -3543800
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (3909036, counted=3921813).
Fix? no


/dev/sda2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda2: 285268/4194304 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 2157610/16777216 blocks
```

However, when I reboot with the partition mounted as readonly e2fsck reports no errors. I then reboot normally to find the ext4 file system is still corrupted.

Anybody have any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's telling you right there:

```
Warning!  /dev/sda2 is mounted.
```

See the man page for more info:

> Note  that  in general it is not safe to run e2fsck on mounted filesystems.  The only exception is if the -n option is specified, and -c, -l, or -L options are not  specified.    However,  even  if  it  is  safe  to  do so, **the results printed by e2fsck are not valid if the
>          filesystem is mounted.**   If e2fsck asks whether or not you should check a  filesystem  which
>          is  mounted,  **the only correct answer is ``no''.**  Only experts who really know what they are
>          doing should consider answering this question in any other way.

It's nice to  use a live ISO for checking root filesystems without having them mounted at all.

And, it's possible your disk is just going bad, make backups & try a safe / unmounted `e2fsck` with the `-c` (read-only) or `-cc` (non-destructive read-write *according to the man page*) options to check with badblocks.

Comment: I believe your answer is not correct as it stands. 

I did this following [instructions I found online](http://bitsofmymind.com/2014/03/14/how-to-fix-fsck-your-root-file-system-that-you-have-to-boot-into-on-linux/) that say it should be first mounted as **read-only** so no files are open in write-mode at the time e2fsck is run and that it will do its job fine. The warning you see is when I run e2fsck from a user run level. At run level 1 it shows **no errors** as I stated in my OP.

Also, it wouldn't be able to run the check if the 'e2fsck' binary has to be read from that partition.

Comment: Well, if you only see errors while it's mounted `rw`, that may be the only problem. If you still think the man page is not correct, you'd have to take that up with the e2fsck maintainers (I think Theodore Ts'o still does a lot himself) they've got far more experience than I. Also, I'm sure there are boot codes and other ways to force a `fsck` at boot time too, probably better than just `tune2fs` to change the max-mount-count or mount-count too, I'll edit in some other ideas to the answer